# How does angular handle @ sign in view path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I am looking at datalake aws sources. Their [package.js](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-lake-solution/blob/master/source/console/app/package/package.js) contains:

```
'@package': {
    templateUrl: 'package/package.html',
    controller: 'PackageCtrl'
}
```

How does angularjs handle the `@package`? If it is needed to point controller to `package` path they can just define `package` without `@`, no?

**UPDATED**

The url when this controller works is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/package/someId`

Comment: @package is the state, isn't it? So I guess that's simply their URL structure - like /#/@package

Comment: Url example was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it in the docs of ui-router:

> if an @ is used then the view path is considered absolute

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

As far as I understand, you use @package to target the unnamed view in index.html with the "package" state. This becomes useful whenever you have nested views.